# HTML anchor inside a table

Tags: css, asp.net, html, anchor

The tr id element is not working as a destination for links.

I am trying to create the link www.mywebsite.com/page1.asp#row1

Each of these rows has a picture and description that I need to have go to a distinct url.

The code below is the closest that I have gotten, but it is still not working and I do not know why.

I am building this website in Volusion. This HTML is going into a content block within an already built framework.

```html
<table>
     <colgroup><col width="30%">
     </colgroup>
<tbody>
  <tr id = "row1">
    <td><div style="text-align: center;"><img src="/img1.JPG" alt="" align="top" border="0px"></div></td>
    <td valign="top">1st Image</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr id = "row2">
    <td><div style="text-align: center;"><img src="/img2.JPG=" align="top" border="0px"></div></td>
    <td valign="top">2nd Image</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr id = "row3">
    <td><div style="text-align: center;"><img src="/img3.JPG" alt="" align="top" border="0px"></div></td>
    <td valign="top">3rd Image</td> 
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Might be unrelated but you have a code error in "row2"
`<img src="/img2.JPG="" ...`
should be `<img src="/img2.JPG" ...`

Comment: Thanks for the edit. It is unrelated though.

Comment: Seems to work for me http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YZwjjr. If that isn't working, what browser/OS are you using? And does anything happen when you click on the links?

Comment: This should work as-is - https://jsfiddle.net/c7f1wc1v/ - Maybe it is something related to server-side asp rendering.

Comment: Thats what I'm afraid of! I'll post more detail tomorrow with the actual code.

Comment: Try moving the id to the <div> in each case.

Answer (score 0):

The path for the image is wrong I guess. Maybe once check the path like there might be another folder you may have forgot to add (like image/img1.jpg). or maybe try ./ instead of /. Also img2 src is wrong. please correct it

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with my images. The images render correctly.